# WCF RIA OData/SOAP endpoint usage limitations

Tags: silverlight, wcf, web-services, windows-phone-7

I have a small Silverlight app, using WCF RIA for getting and manipulating data. I was thinking what modifications I have to make to port the app to WP7 or other platforms.
The DomainContext proxy generated in the SL app is not supported in WP7 afaik. (Am I right on this?)

So I think my options are exposing OData or SOAP (or JSON) endpoints for the DomainService. A lot of sources say that OData is pretty limited, but what about the DataServiceContext class? Is this almost as functional as the DomainContext? I mean it tracks my downloaded entities, and when I save the changes, it saves the tracked modifications to the server, and this is very useful I think.

But what about the SOAP endpoint, or platforms which don't have so many features like the WP7 DataServiceContext? How can I make modifications in this case? Do i have to track every change manually, and for example if I want to insert 45 entities, I have to insert them one-by-one with a basic insert (CRUD) method? (The generated service proxies are doing the same in the background btw?)

So to sum up my questions, which approach is the best, and the most platform independent? I think SOAP is the choice, but since I never developed on Android or iOS, i'm not sure. And also I'm not sure if I can send back IQueryable in every endpoint (or there is an equivalent on every platform?). If I can't, do i have to modify all my custom queries in the wcf ria domain service, to suite the limitations of SOAP?